# I was working on my application, reopened it after a while and all .xml files have gradle content in them now

Tags: android

As stated in the title, I was working on a project in Android Studio and then left to do other things. When I opened it back up, my xml files no longer had their xml content. They have what appears to be stuff that normally goes in the gradle, and the gradle has java class stuff in it. I don't know how this happened, how do I fix it?? That's hours of work down the drain!

Comment: There is just no way for us to know what you did there. No, gremlins don't change files behind your back.

Comment: Everything worked just fine when I closed it, I didn't do anything. I even tried going back to a previous version, it's all still broken.

Comment: Undo whatever changes you made ever since after the last time your app was compiling. It's impossible for anyone to help you with this one.

Comment: try sync manually